# What method will alert the browser that an image has changed?

Tags: javascript

I break the image cache by simply appending a

```
?time=current_time_stamp
```

to my image urls when making a request.

However, I only need to break the cache immediately after the user has updated their photo.

I could add a timestamp to every image request of the user photo, but this seems like over-kill.

Is there a way to tell the browser, the image has been updated, please refresh your cache.

Otherwise I would need to append a time stamp or similar to all dynamic images, to catch any changes in the image.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of adding `?time=some_time_stamp`, why not add `?time=time_last_modified`? You can retrieve this value from the filesystem, *or* store it in a DB yourself.

Comment: What's `some_time_stamp`? The update time of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is do modify the filename of the image on the server whenever the image changes so that when the image changes, the browser HTML contains a reference to the new filename and thus the browser requests the new filename (which is not in the cache).  The filename can contain a version number which you increase any time the file is modified or you could just use a timestamp as part of the filename.

This gives you the best of both worlds.  You get maximum caching in the browser when the image has not changed, but you also get immediately update when the image changes.

Also relevant here is that the server can control the caching directives on each individual element to instruct the browser whether it can cache or not or for how long.

Comment: It was so easy to simply update the file name in the sql table with and _1, _2, etc. + now I can track how many uploads there have been.